# Both Rendered viewport and final render are blurry after processing

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, 3d-view, blur

I have followed Blender Guru's tutorial on modelling the donut, cup, plate and table, however, at some point along the way of getting there something happened. Both in my rendered viewport and when I try to render a picture of all the objects, it all gets blurry. You can see how it is working on the particles in order to render it, but at one point it decides to blur everything. The final render is all blurred up. Could you please help me with this? I tried playing with all the settings, reached 5th page of google looking through forums, but I could not solve it. I am quite desperate. Thank you very much, I really appreciate it. Have a great day!

Edit: [image]

Comment: Can you add your blend file to your question?  It would make it easier to understand.  To do this:
Grab the URL of the question
Go to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/
Select the blend file
Add the url of the question
Grab the url that results
Go back to the question and edit it
Add the new url to the bottom of the post

Comment: It sure looks like a depth of field issue, but I can't find anything wrong with your settings.  I'll look for something else.

Comment: Well I am stumped for now. I have never seen this. But I found a work around. Just start a new project then append all the objects except for the camera. Then everything worked correctly.

Comment: Also you had weird scaling (in the negatives) on some of your objects and also be careful you had square samples set to 200 thats 40,000 samples and would take 5 years to render.

Answer (score 2):

Under the film tab you had Blackman-Harris at value 10.00, and the default is 1.50.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/settings/scene/render/film.html

Comment: Good job, havent run into that one before.